# Is it possible to access embedded layer QWidget from QGIS Console?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-custom-widgets

My goal is to get access/control to `QWidget` state from QGIS Console. For example, to be able to trigger `QPushButton.click()` event. Is there a method to get reference to `QWidget` (in particular `QgsLayerTreeEmbeddedWidget` like on a screenshot)?

1. The widget is created by [Layer tiles mapcanvas](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/layertilesmapcanvas/)
2. I managed to get to `QgsGui.layerTreeRegistry()`, but `QgsGui.layerTreeEmbeddedWidgetRegistry().provider('LayerTilesMapCanvasWidgetProvider')` returns provider and not the widget itself.

The widget looks like this:

[image: EmbeddedWidget]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `QObject.findChildren(self, type type, QString name = QString())` method to access any nested widgets in the interface.

To trigger the `QPushButton` you could do the following in the console:

```
b = [button for button in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QPushButton) if button.text() == 'OK']
b[0].click()
```

This will of course only work if there is not multiple buttons with a text of `OK`. To really make sure you got the correct button (and get a reference to the `QgsLayerTreeEmbeddedWidget`, if that's also required):

```
from layertilesmapcanvas.layertilesmapcanvas import LayerTilesMapCanvasWidget
widget = iface.mainWindow().findChild(LayerTilesMapCanvasWidget)

# then again search for the button and trigger click
# this time only searches within children of the known correct widget.
[button for button in widget.findChildren(QPushButton) if button.text() == 'OK'][0].click()
```